# Angles with equal sines and cosines

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having the classic trouble of knowing what I mean, but not knowing how to express it in the best way possible.

Suppose we have $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$ and $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$. Then obviously $x$ and $y$ differ by some multiple of $2 \pi$. But what would be the most direct way of showing this? The best I have is by dividing $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$ by $\sin(x)/ \sin(y)$ to get $\tan(x) = \tan(y)$, and then by using some argument that both of the constituent cosines are the same sign, we have that $x$ and $y$ differ by a multiple of $2 \pi$. You can then deal with the case $\sin(x) = 0$ separately. This feels sloppy and hand-wavey to me though.

Can anyone think of a slicker way of doing this?

Comment: Note that $\sin(x+2\pi n)= \sin x \cos 2\pi n - \cos x \sin 2\pi n=\sin x$ for $n$ integer. Similarly with cosines.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky True, but if $x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$, then there will also $\exists y \in (0,2 \pi)$ such that $\sin(x +y) = \sin(x)$ as well.

Comment: example please:)

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \sin(\frac{3 \pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: well, it was supposed to show that the $2\pi n$ step works... if you put $y$ instead of $2\pi n$ you get exactly the $\tan x=\tan y$ case..., the approved answer is still talking about the same step of $2 pi n$...neither have the solution in your example...which is $\pi/2$ step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive from your data $\cos(x-y)=1$, which gives $x-y=2k\pi$.

Comment: Nice and straightforward. I'll accept it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use this formula $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$
and 
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$